# String comparison of numeric string with actual string in javascirpt

Tags: javascript

when i compare "5">"r" it gives false and "r">"5" it turns out to be true, what is the logic behind in JavaScript?

Comment: Well if `A > B` is false then either `A == B` or `A < B` (i.e. `B > A`). So that's not surprising. If you are asking why the string `5` should be deemed "smaller" than the string `r` you have to look at encodings. The choice was made decades ago and was arbitrary.

Comment: The algorithm is explained in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than#description) for `<` (which applies similar logic for `>`) (always check the docs first and research before asking a question :-) )

Comment: A>B is logical and straight forward you can compare. but for example in case of numeric string and number , JavaScript convert the numeric string to a number and do the comparison but here one is a string which cant be converted to a number and the other is a string which can be converted to a number so am just queries how the comparison is done.

Comment: @Rediat from the docs link in the above comment: _"If both values are strings, they are compared as strings, based on the values of the Unicode code points they contain."_. `"5"` has a code point value of `53` and `"r"` has `114`. It's like comparing `53 > 114` and `114 > 53`